# update database with new lists after dragging&dropping

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, html

We have a generated list of different `<ul>`’s which contains an amount of `<li>`’s. These `<li>`’s are swapped between `<ul>`’s by drag and drop function. When the `<li>` are switched we want to be able to update our database with the `<li>`’s new positions. Can anyone help?

[image]

Ex. There are 3 different groups and we want to switch `Ida Lind Balle Damgaard` with `Allan Arntzen Melkajer`
And then update the new groups.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".grupper li").draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone",
            cursor: "move",
            revert: "invalid"
        });

        initDroppable($(".grupper li"));
        function initDroppable($elements) {
            $elements.droppable({
                activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                hoverClass: "ui-drop-hover",
                accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",

                over: function(event, ui) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                },
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var li1 = $('<li>' + ui.draggable.text() + '</li>')
                    var linew1 = $(this).after(li1);

                    var li2 = $('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>')
                    var linew2 = $(ui.draggable).after(li2);

                    $(ui.draggable).remove();
                    $(this).remove();

                    initDroppable($(".grupper li"));
                    $(".grupper li").draggable({
                        appendTo: "body",
                        helper: "clone",
                        cursor: "move",
                        revert: "invalid"
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>

     <?php
require_once '../connection.php';
require_once '../globalfunctions.php';
globalfunctions();

$query = "SELECT gruppeid FROM studerende ORDER BY gruppeid_redigeret DESC";
$result = select_query($query, $connection);
$result = query_to_array($result);
$antalgrupper = $result[0][0];

for($f=1; $f<=$antalgrupper; $f++){
    echo '<ul class="grupper" id=gruppe' . $f . ">";
    $query = "SELECT id, fornavn, efternavn FROM studerende WHERE gruppeid_redigeret = " . $f . " ORDER BY fornavn ASC, efternavn ASC";
    $result = select_query($query, $connection);
    $result = query_to_array($result);
    echo "<h3> Gruppe " . $f . "</h3>";
    for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){
        echo '<li class="ui-droppable" name="' . $result[$i][0] . '">' . $result[$i][1] . " " . $result[$i][2] . "</li>";
    }        
    echo "</ul>";
}



mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```